# How to mask secret values from log files in splunk UI?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have my logs coming to /var/logs/messages file in Splunk UI. Now whenever the logs come, it also sends secret and access keys . I want to mask the secret and access keys with something like `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= gjhsagd#########` . How can we update the value in SPLUNK UI.

Answer (score 3):

On your Indexer (or Heavy Forwarder, if you're using it), you need to include the following in your `props.conf`

```
SEDCMD-awskey = s/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\s+/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=###/g
```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of `props.conf` and `transforms.conf`

props.conf

```
[aws*]
TRANSFORMS-awskey = awssecretkey
```

transforms.conf

```
[ticket-awssecretkey]
REGEX = (?m)^(.*)AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\s+(.*)$
FORMAT = $1AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=########$2
DEST_KEY = _raw
```

More details and examples can be found at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/Data/Anonymizedata

Comment: Hey @simon, Thanks for the answer , it helps . But my string is something like this {"name":"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","value":"q2*****Uc9JjFdQlu4KYrbAWXpGQK/"} , how can i add for this so that the value becomes "value":"q2gfdjahUc###########" something like this.

Comment: `[ticket-awssecretkey]`

`REGEX = (?m)(.*)AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","value":"(....).*"(.*)`

`FORMAT = $1AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","value":"$2####"$3`

`DEST_KEY = _raw`